# How to open a jQuery ui dialogue on clicking of HTML table cell

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, html-table

I have a HTML table. Now as per my requirement I want to open a jQuery Ui dialogue as soon as table cell gets clicked..

Here is my HTML table..

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Header Column</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><th>Header</th><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td><td>Cell 4</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Header</th><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td><td>Cell 4</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Header</th><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td><td>Cell 4</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Header</th><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td><td>Cell 4</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('td').click(function () {
        var dialog = $('<p>This is the sample dialog</p>').dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Submit": function () {
                    //Your submit handler
                }
            },
            title:'Your title',
        });
    });
});
```

For centering the button:

```
.ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content{
    text-align:center;
}
.ui-dialog-buttonset{
    float:none!important;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Demo :
http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/97/

Comment: Sir i wan to give only submit button at center of the dialogue

Comment: You can remove remaining buttons from the code. Only keep a single button and name it as per your needs.

Comment: I did but the submit button is not at center of the dialogue

Comment: Sir how to add title in dialogue sir

Comment: Refer this link: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/ It has all the options you want to know for dialog.

Comment: Actually sir i am not getting where to add title code in the function..Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

In case u have table already in the html

```
$('table tbody tr td').click(function() {

     // ur code for showing dialog here

});
```

In case u r dynamically generating the table

u need to bind the event using on() method

```
$('table tbody tr td').on('click', function() {

         // ur code for showing dialog here

});
```

or

```
$(document).on('click', 'table tbody tr td', function() {

         // ur code for showing dialog here

    });
```

'table tbody tr td' can be the identifier for the cell.. it may be any classname for the cells also

Answer (score 0):

Use a class to identify your table cells:

```
<tbody>
    <tr><th>Header</th><td class="clickable">Cell 2</td><td class="clickable">Cell 3</td><td class="clickable">Cell 4</td></tr>
 <!-- the rest of your table -->
</tbody>

you may use a jquery class selector binding a click event like that:

$(".clickable").click(function(){
//put here the code for opening your dialogue
})
```